# Multiplicative Input-Dependent Noise

Tags: noise, continuous-signals

This question might not be exactly suitable to the question format of StackExchange but I couldn't find a better way to put it forward.

Lately, I have been dealing with ECG Signal processing and due to the characteristic of this specific channel, there is some multiplicative noise correlated with the ECG signal.

I am having difficulties to model this type of noise which depends on the input itself and has the same frequency with it. My question may sound very vague but I am looking for some tips to conduct further research because I am also not very experienced in the mathematical modeling of such systems.

Comment: Hm, by correlated do you mean "only correlated to the instantaneous signal amplitude" or "a random process with a nonzero cross-correlation function with the signal (even for white signals)"? Maybe a plot or something might help explain your situation?

Comment: The desired signal (ECG) has its source from the electrical activity of the heart. The mechanical activation, coming a bit later, is affecting the measurement channel, which makes it a non-linear time-variant system. When I try to approach analytically, these two signal are multiplicated at some point. However, they have the same frequency with different waveforms and also a bit time-delay.